# Net::HTTP::Post fails while calling spaces url with argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, google-cloud-platform

I have this code to send notifications to google spaces from my Rails code. The notifications are going out but one of the lines gives error. I tried with different ways of calling it but strange it keep failing in the mid.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse("https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAAAAAA/messages?key=AIzaSyDddsdHDSDS-WEfzqKqqsHI&token=OaX6LQKRyIC8aSUXH8cnuKZXAII%3D")
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data = {
  "text": "Bijendra-Test Notification!"
}
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
request.body = data.to_json
response = http.request(request)
```

Error:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
Traceback (most recent call last):
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments calling `method` (given 1, expected 0))
```

Since request is initialized with this error, it gets the body in next line of code and send the notification.
Rails - 5.2, jruby-9.3.3.0

Comment: Is that the complete stack trace?

Comment: also could you post the version of Ruby and the exact version of the `net-http` gem from your Gemfile.lock

Comment: @iftheshoefritz yes it's the complete stack trace. Net::HTTP is built in. updated other details

Answer (score 0):

Your exact code with a URL I can access (`URI.parse("https://httpbin.org/anything?id=anotherthing")`) gives me no errors on jruby 9.3.3.0 or C Ruby 2.7.6.

(I get a 400 API key error for your chat.googleapis URL, which I assume is correct)

That makes me think that the problem is the specific response you're getting from Google vs the parsing that net/http does.

To confirm this, you can try with the same URL I used. If that works, then it's worth posting a sanitised version of the google response so that people here can help you understand what the specific issue is.